# EXC_BAD_ACESS while accessing class variable

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have assigned class varaible as....

```
  [MyINFO setUsrID:[dict valueForKey:USERID]];
```

but when i access "usrID"  on another view controller it gives EXC_BAD_ACESS error.
Please suggest what changes should be done in MyINFO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class variables do not work this way in Objective-C.  You can create a singleton class and use instance variables of the singleton.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good Matt Gallagher post about Singletons, along with a clever macro for creating singletons in Objective-C.  [You can read it here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html).